# Debian checkinstall ignores install=no; how to have it build, but NOT autoinstall a package?

Tags: debian, checkinstall

Ok, here is one thing that puzzles me... I'm trying to build a package from source, and then use `checkinstall` to generate a .deb package. Note that I want to just create the .deb package, but I do NOT want to *install* it.

So, here's an example - I'm on Ubuntu 11.04, and first I install it's `feh` package from the default repositories; which has a version number apparently being [1.3.4.dfsg.1-3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/feh)

Then I'm trying to build `feh` [from source](http://feh.finalrewind.org/); got `make` to pass, and can run the new `feh` from the command line; splendid.

Now finally, to create a deb package, I use the following command line:

```
sudo checkinstall -D -y \
  --install=no \
  --fstrans=no \
  --reset-uids=yes \
  --pkgname=feh \
  --pkgversion=2.7 \
  --pkgrelease="tar.bz2" \
  --arch=i386 \
  --pkglicense=GPL \
  --maintainer="Debian PhotoTools Maintainers <pkg-phototools-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>" \
  --pakdir=../.. \
  --requires=libc6,libice6,libsm6,libx11-6,libxaw7,libxext6,libxmu6,libxt6,dpkg,install-info
```

OK, notice that I've used **`--install=no`** there? Even `man checkinstall` says:

> --install Toggle installation of the created package.

Well, this is what this `checkinstall` command replies:

```
checkinstall 1.6.2, Copyright 2009 Felipe Eduardo Sanchez Diaz Duran
           This software is released under the GNU GPL.

/usr/bin/checkinstall: eval: line 598: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/usr/bin/checkinstall: eval: line 598: `echo Debian PhotoTools Maintainers <pkg-phototools-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>'

The package documentation directory ./doc-pak does not exist. 
Should I create a default set of package docs?  [y]: y

Preparing package documentation...OK

*****************************************
**** Debian package creation selected ***
*****************************************

This package will be built according to these values: 

0 -  Maintainer: [ root@mypc ]
1 -  Summary: [ Package created with checkinstall 1.6.2 ]
2 -  Name:    [ feh ]
3 -  Version: [ 2.7 ]
4 -  Release: [ tar.bz2 ]
5 -  License: [ GPL ]
6 -  Group:   [ checkinstall ]
7 -  Architecture: [ i386 ]
8 -  Source location: [ feh-2.7 ]
9 -  Alternate source location: [  ]
10 - Requires: [ libc6,libice6,libsm6,libx11-6,libxaw7,libxext6,libxmu6,libxt6,dpkg,install-info ]
11 - Provides: [ feh ]
12 - Conflicts: [  ]
13 - Replaces: [  ]

Enter a number to change any of them or press ENTER to continue: 

Installing with make install...

========================= Installation results ===========================
installing manuals to /usr/local/share/man
installing docs to /usr/local/share/doc/feh
installing executables to /usr/local/bin
installing fonts to /usr/local/share/feh/fonts
installing images to /usr/local/share/feh/images
installing examples to /usr/local/share/doc/feh/examples

======================== Installation successful ==========================
```

NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!!!!!

I did NOT want the damn package to INSTALL -- THAT IS WHY I USED `--install=no` FOR CRYIN OUT LOUD!!!

And then, apparently in an attempt to be sarcastic, the log continues:

```
Copying documentation directory...
./
./TODO
./AUTHORS
./COPYING
./ChangeLog
./README

Copying files to the temporary directory...OK

Stripping ELF binaries and libraries...OK

Compressing man pages...OK

Building file list...OK

Building Debian package...OK

NOTE: The package will not be installed
```

You must be kidding with this "*NOTE: The package will not be installed*", right, Mr. `checkinstall`? Sure you are; after this is done, note what I get:

```
$ apt-cache show feh | grep Version
Version: 1.10-1

$ feh --version
feh version 2.7
Compile-time switches: curl xinerama 

$ which feh
/usr/local/bin/feh
```

Not sure where that `1.10-1` came from (it should have been at least `1.3.4`, as per above?) - but its damn obvious that the 2.7 DID get installed, IN SPITE of my instruction NOT to install...

Surely, I can try to remove afterwards:

```
$ sudo dpkg -r feh
(Reading database ... 202193 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing feh ...
$ sudo dpkg --purge feh
(Reading database ... 202163 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing feh ...
Purging configuration files for feh ...
$ feh --version
feh version 2.7
Compile-time switches: curl xinerama 
$ which feh
/usr/local/bin/feh
```

... but not even `dpkg --purge` works (`apt-get remove` wouldn't work to begin with, since it's a manually installed .deb package). And besides `dpkg -r` not  giving a version (so I'm not really sure what it is that should have been removed) - it in fact did NOT remove the bloody executable ?!

But can anyone explain what is going here - and how to get `checkinstall` to *only* generate a .deb, and NOT install it at the same time? Bonus question - how to remove ALL files, *including* executables in `/usr/local/bin/`, that got installed in this way - since apparently `dpkg -r` doesn't work?

Comment: I'm puzzled. Why do you want to install from source, if you have a binary package?

Comment: and how did you fix the error about --maintainer ?

Comment: I took a look at the checkinstall sources RE: the --maintainer error. The issue is the the result of unquoted < and > symbols. So the easy answer is: don't use symbols. The more problematic answer is that there is a serious problem with checkinstall. The entire source is littered with ``eval echo $1``... It should actually be ``eval "echo '$1'"``. I guess I'll try to get in touch with the author or something.

Answer (score 13):

Right; I think I finally understood what is happening - key line I missed is:

```
Installing with make install...
```

This means that the `make install` of the 2.7 source package was run - probably in order to "see" where those files will eventually end up, so as to write those locations in the new .deb? But in any case, the new 2.7 .deb indeed didn't get installed - and that is why it couldn't be removed with `dpkg -r`, and the executable was still lingering even after `dpkg -r`.

So to remove this installation after running `checkinstall`, one should actually call `make uninstall` from the `feh` source folder:

```
$ make uninstall
rm -f /usr/local/share/man/man1/feh.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/feh-cam.1
rm -f /usr/local/share/man/man1/gen-cam-menu.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/doc/feh
rm: cannot remove `/usr/local/share/doc/feh/TODO': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/usr/local/share/doc/feh/examples/keys': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/usr/local/share/doc/feh/examples/themes': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/usr/local/share/doc/feh/examples/buttons': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/usr/local/share/doc/feh/AUTHORS': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/usr/local/share/doc/feh/ChangeLog': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/usr/local/share/doc/feh/README': Permission denied
make: *** [uninstall] Error 1

$ sudo make uninstall
rm -f /usr/local/share/man/man1/feh.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/feh-cam.1
rm -f /usr/local/share/man/man1/gen-cam-menu.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/doc/feh
rm -f /usr/local/bin/feh /usr/local/bin/feh-cam /usr/local/bin/gen-cam-menu
rm -rf /usr/local/share/feh/fonts
rm -rf /usr/local/share/feh/images
```

... and then finally I can try the newly created package:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i feh_2.7-tar.bz2_i386.deb 
Selecting previously deselected package feh.
(Reading database ... 202165 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking feh (from feh_2.7-tar.bz2_i386.deb) ...
Setting up feh (2.7-tar.bz2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...

$ feh --version
feh version 2.7
Compile-time switches: curl xinerama 

$ sudo dpkg --purge feh
(Reading database ... 202198 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing feh ...
dpkg: warning: while removing feh, directory '/usr/local/share/doc' not empty so not removed.
Processing triggers for man-db ...

$ feh --version
bash: /usr/local/bin/feh: No such file or directory

# or in new terminal 
$ feh --version
The program 'feh' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install feh
```

Oh well.... hope I understood correctly how the process goes now, though..

Answer (score 6):

One should change *fstrans* to *yes* to ensure checkinstall will not touch the real filetree

```
--fstrans=yes
```

Comment: I used this switch in combination with `--install=no` and the files were installed but `dpkg` was not updated.

Answer (score 5):

You can install "twice":

1. Via the package which you created. You can switch it off by `--install=no`
2. Via the make. You can switch it off by simply typing `make` (without `install`)

Examples:

- No installation at all:

  `sudo checkinstall --install=no make`
- An installation via make:

  `sudo checkinstall --install=no make install`

Comment: I think this is the best answer.

Comment: "sudo checkinstall --install=no --fstrans=yes make" worked for me. I mixed this answer with this one: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170170/156284

Answer (score -1):

You should try to use:

```
sudo checkinstall --install=no make -n install
```

Answer (score -1):

Use: sudo checkinstall -D make -n install

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: `make -n install` does stop `make` from actually installing the files, but `checkinstall` doesn't properly interpret the results.  You end up with a deb file not containing all of the files you need.  So, this doesn't work.